# css animation doesnt appear first when going onto second html page

Tags: html, css

Hi I am doing an assignment that recquires me to only use html and css only no javascript. Usually, with javascript this is hella easy to do but html and css only is a bit annoying. In my first page I have a link to my second but when I press the link from the first page to go onto the second page. The animation I made does not work at all and the secondary text only shows up.

I will provide photos and code to show what I mean. I dont understand what I am doing incorrectly to cause this but it is annoying.

[firstpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOYAp.png)

[second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtLao.png)

from the first page going onto the second via clicking 'start' the second text only shows up but I need the whole thing to show up. Heres the animation part I want to show up as well. [animation_part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx3l7.png)

second page html:
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv5xo.png)
second page css
[css-part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9M5E.png)
[css-part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xfIJ.png)

I am not sure if this will further show my predicament but heres the code for the first html and css pages:

For some reason it is not allowing me to post the code here so I have done my best to showcase to go around the error

GITHUB: https://github.com/TheGraeDev/ADV201

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that your required character went to the back of main background. Try changes in css to bring your panda to front. Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried that via using z index and the problem was still there..... I am so confused as to why its refusing to do it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Okay Incase anyone else comes across the same issue. Change position to relative and instead of using percentage value for Top in css using px. it fixed the problem